# Date Picker Dialog using Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm developing an Android application using Xamarin and want to set the date on an editText field using a datePicker. When we click on editText the datePicker opens but when the date is set then the date is not shown on editText. What is wrong in the provided code.

Thanks in advance.

```
 public class PageFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        int _num;
        database baseObj = new database();
        EditText datePickerText;

        DatePickerDialog Date;
        View v;
        public PageFragment()
        {
        }
        public PageFragment(int num)
        {
            // Supply num input as an argument.
            var args = new Bundle();
            args.PutInt("num", num);
            Arguments = args;
        }
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            _num = Arguments != null ? Arguments.GetInt("num") : 1;
        }
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.distribution, container, false);
            datePickerText = v.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextCalender);
            datePickerText.Focusable = false;
            datePickerText.Click += delegate
            {
                var dialog = new DatePickerDialogFragment(Activity, DateTime.Now, null);
                dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "date");
            };
            return v;

        }
        public void OnDateSet(Android.Widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            v.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextCalender).Text = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth).ToString();
        }
        public class DatePickerDialogFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.DialogFragment
        {
            private readonly Context _context;
            private DateTime _date;
            private readonly DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener _listener;
            public DatePickerDialogFragment(Context context, DateTime date, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener listener)
            {
                _context = context;
                _date = date;
                _listener = listener;
            }
            public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
            {
                var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(_context, _listener, _date.Year, _date.Month - 1, _date.Day);
                return dialog;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at our sample: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/datepicker/select_a_date/

Comment: But we use Inside a fragment Tab where problem in This Code Please Suggest.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't see that. here is your sample: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/fragment/select_a_date_in_a_fragment/

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite late to answer your problem. Hope you have solved your problem though. I have got the answer why editTextCalender can not show the date you set through DatePickerDialog. You got to change following lines of code

```
 public void OnDateSet(Android.Widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        v.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextCalender).Text = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth).ToString();
    }
```

into(Correct one)

```
 public void OnDateSet(Android.Widget.DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
    {
        datePickerText.Text = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth).ToString();
    }
```

Because you have already inflated `datePickerText = v.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editTextCalender);` while creating view before you handle click event on it.

Thank you!